# Howto Restore/Recover whole Netbeans Java project from Dropbox once current laptop is dead?

Tags: java, git, netbeans, dropbox

I have created my Netbeans Java project directly into my Dropbox folder, in which I also have initialized a Git repository to track changes. Therefore my question about how I can recover/restore this Netbeans Java Project along with its Git repo onto another laptop in case my current laptop is dead?

Comment: Install the Dropbox client on the other Laptop, restore the project like any other file from Dropbox, open it in Netbeans. If absolute paths are different on that laptop (e.g. JDK path) you can fix them in the project settings. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi Sub, lemme try if this works. I will post a feedback later.